# Django testing on separate database giving "OperationalError: no such table: auth_user"

Tags: django, sqlite, python-3.x, ldap, django-rest-framework

My problem is that I wanted to put up a separate testing database, separate from my development database. App itself is almost identical to Django-Rest-Framework quick-start tutorial, just that I use LDAP backend. My development database uses MySQL. I have separate settings file for testing.

Full error traceback I put in here: http://dpaste.com/1W3TX1E, but interesting part is:

```
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: auth_user
```

Full test-settings are here: http://dpaste.com/1K7KHK4. My related settings are (pyldap and django-ldap-auth are missing from installed apps, they are installed manually with pip):

```
    INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'njord',
    'permissions',
]
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': ':memory:',
    }
}
```

Right now the app does basically only authentication with LDAP. I think that is why I have an error - when I do tests I have nothing in my database - no users, no groups. If a user is authenticated against LDAP server, user is created in database alongside with all the groups he/she is in, so it happens on-demand.

What works: Development version of my app works well against external LDAP and also testing works with development database.

What does not work: Testing with sqllite3 in-memory database(I repeat, testing with development database and mocked ldap works).

The code I test with is here:

```
from django.test import TestCase, Client
import django
import ldap

from mockldap import MockLdap

class AuthenticationTests(TestCase):
    """
    Set Up the structure  ( Accounts, Groups ) and try authentication
    """
    # Top level hierarchy
    top = ('dc=ee', {'dc': ['ee']})
    test = ('dc=test,dc=ee', {'dc': ['test']})

    # Top level groups
    people = ('ou=people,dc=test,dc=ee', {'ou': ['people'], 'objectClass': ['organizationalUnit', 'top']})
    groups = ('ou=groups,dc=test,dc=ee', {'ou': ['groups'], 'objectClass': ['organizationalUnit', 'top']})

    # Groups
    admins = ('cn=admins,ou=groups,dc=test,dc=ee', {'cn': ['admins'], 'memberUid': ['admin'],
                                                'objectClass': ['sambaGroupMapping', 'posixGroup', 'top'],
                                                'gidNumber': ['1']})

    group1 = ('cn=group1,ou=groups,dc=test,dc=ee', {'cn': ['group1'],
                                                'memberUid': ['alice', 'bob'],
                                      'objectClass': ['sambaGroupMapping', 'posixGroup', 'top']})

    group2 = ('cn=group2,ou=groups,dc=test,dc=ee', {'cn': ['group2'], 'memberUid': ['admin', 'bob', 'karl'],
                                      'objectClass': ['sambaGroupMapping', 'posixGroup', 'top']})

    # Users
    admin = ('uid=admin,ou=people,dc=test,dc=ee', {'uid': ['admin'], 'userPassword': ['ldaptest'], 'sn': ['Joe'],
                                               'cn': ['Admin Joe'], 'mail': ['admin.joe@test.ee'],
                                               'givenName': ['Admin'], 'objectClass':
                                                   ['top', 'person', 'posixAccount', 'shadowAccount',
                                                    'inetOrgPerson', 'sambaSamAccount']})

    alice = ('uid=alice,ou=people,dc=test,dc=ee', {'uid': ['alice'], 'userPassword': ['ldaptest'], 'sn': ['Cooper'],
                                               'cn': ['Alice Cooper'], 'mail': ['alice.cooper@test.ee'],
                                               'givenName': ['Alice'], 'objectClass':
                                                   ['top', 'person', 'posixAccount', 'shadowAccount',
                                                    'inetOrgPerson', 'sambaSamAccount']})

    bob = ('uid=bob,ou=people,dc=test,dc=ee', {'uid': ['bob'], 'userPassword': ['ldaptest'], 'sn': ['Marley'],
                                           'cn': ['Bob Marley'], 'mail': ['bob.marley@test.ee'],
                                           'givenName': ['Bob'], 'objectClass':
                                               ['top', 'person', 'posixAccount', 'shadowAccount',
                                                'inetOrgPerson', 'sambaSamAccount']})

    karl = ('uid=karl,ou=people,dc=test,dc=ee', {'uid': ['karl'], 'userPassword': ['ldaptest'], 'sn': ['Suur'],
                                             'cn': ['Karl Suur'], 'mail': ['karl.suur@test.ee'],
                                             'givenName': ['Karl'], 'objectClass':
                                                 ['top', 'person', 'posixAccount', 'shadowAccount',
                                                  'inetOrgPerson', 'sambaSamAccount']})

    # This is the content of our mock LDAP directory. It takes the form
    # {dn: {attr: [value, ...], ...}, ...}.
    directory = dict([top, test, people, groups, admins, group1, group2, admin, alice, bob, karl])

    @classmethod
    def setUpTestData(cls):
        # We only need to create the MockLdap instance once. The content we
        # pass in will be used for all LDAP connections.
        cls.mockldap = MockLdap(cls.directory)

    @classmethod
    def tearDownClass(cls):
        del cls.mockldap

    def setUp(self):
        # Patch ldap.initialize
        django.setup()
        self.mockldap.start()
        self.ldapobj = self.mockldap['ldap://localhost/']

    def tearDown(self):
        # Stop patching ldap.initialize and reset state.
        self.mockldap.stop()
        del self.ldapobj

    def test_some_basic_mockldap_auth(self):
        searchStr = 'uid=alice,ou=people,dc=test,dc=ee'
        results = _do_simple_ldap_search(searchStr)
        ldapName = results[0][0]
        ldapPropDict = results[0][1]
        self.assertEqual(searchStr, ldapName)
        self.assertEqual(len(ldapPropDict), 7)

    def test_index_visible_for_all(self):
        c = Client()
        response = c.get("/")
        self.assertContains(response, "/users/", 1)
        self.assertContains(response, "/groups/", 1)

    def test_login(self):
        c = Client()
        response = c.post("/api-auth/login/", {'username': 'bob', 'password': 'ldaptest'})
        print(response.status_code)
        response = c.get("/users/")
        print(response._container)

def _do_simple_ldap_search(searchStr):
    conn = ldap.initialize('ldap://localhost/')
    conn.simple_bind_s(searchStr, 'ldaptest')
    results = conn.search_s(searchStr, ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE, )

    return results
```

Code also available here: http://dpaste.com/3D2H4NK (syntax highlight).

I am not sure, what the problem is. Only thing I can think of is that because there are no users in database at the creation, database is not created, but I am not sure. Any help is much appreciated.

I have done all the migrations.

```
(venv)user@box:~/workspace/fileshare/njord$ python manage.py showmigrationsadmin
 [X] 0001_initial
 [X] 0002_logentry_remove_auto_add
auth
 [X] 0001_initial
 [X] 0002_alter_permission_name_max_length
 [X] 0003_alter_user_email_max_length
 [X] 0004_alter_user_username_opts
 [X] 0005_alter_user_last_login_null
 [X] 0006_require_contenttypes_0002
 [X] 0007_alter_validators_add_error_messages
contenttypes
 [X] 0001_initial
 [X] 0002_remove_content_type_name
sessions
 [X] 0001_initial
(venv)user@box:~/workspace/fileshare/njord$ python manage.py makemigrationsNo changes detected
(venv)user@box:~/workspace/fileshare/njord$ python manage.py migrate
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, sessions, auth, contenttypes
Running migrations:
  No migrations to apply.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What had to be done, was add these lines to manage.py:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    if 'test' in sys.argv:
        os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "app.test_settings")
    else:
        os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "app.settings")
```

After adding that if 'test' thing to main method of manage.py, the app started working correctly, after that python manage.py test and python manage.py runserver both worked with correct settings.

However, I have not got this to work with PyCharm and testing it now, how to get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

run
    `python manage.py makemigrations <appname>`
for each applications in `INSTALLED_APPS`.(Specially the apps that has a ForeignKey field on `auth_user`)

I got different error to get me here, but think cause is the same.
`django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1005, "Can't create table '<test_db>.#sql-3821_1c9' (errno: 150)")`

In both cases all tables related to `auth` module are only not created  when testing, without executing `makemigrations` command.
I found the solution from [here](http://amfarrell.com/random-notes/)